# DrawerLayout open slowly

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm working on an app designed to use a DrawerLayout that contains a ListView, and i got an issue whit it . I'm using an ALCATEL IDOL MINI , API 17 to debug.On that phone , the drawer slide normally , even if the content is populated by views and information , also the scroll speed of the ListView is normal.but when i tested my app on another phone (Samsung Galaxy S3 API 19 and Nexus 5 API 21),the drawer slide very slowly with some lags and also the speed of scrolling the ListView inside is slow ,just when the content is populated by views and information. 
It doesn't make any sense because the S3 and Nexus 5 are more powerful .

Comment: How many items are in your ListView?

Comment: How (and when) is it being populated?

Comment: populated by an custum adapter in onCreate() of draweractivity

Comment: This is a performance issue.  There is too much work being done causing the animation skips. If you are using a listview as a menu, you should use NavigationView to prevent any issues with performance.

Comment: I'm using a litview as a sub menu that appear and desappear after a click on item in the drawer, but it looks the same , so you advice me to use navigationView insted of Listview ? i will try this solution

Comment: / i think its not because of the listview !

Comment: A RecyclerView can replace the ListView... but still... 100 items is not really a lot of items.

Comment: it's only 10 items ......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Finally resolved the problem , it was a background image issue , i used a HD image as background of the **drawerlayout** and also the **ListView** , now after i changed the background , the Drawer slide smoothly and items of the List are scrolled smoothly as well.